# hive json data parsing

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

My JSON Data is something like this in the table json_table and column: json_col

```
{
    "href": "example.com",
    "Hosts": {
        "cluster_name": "test",
        "host_name": "test.iabc.com"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "cpu": {
            "cpu_user": [
                [
                    0.7,
                    1499795941
                ],
                [
                    0.3,
                    1499795951
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get this into a table **json_data** in the below format

```
+-------------+-------+------------+
| metric_type | value | timestamp  |
+-------------+-------+------------+
| cpu_user    | 0.7   | 1499795941 |
+-------------+-------+------------+
| cpu_user    | 0.3   | 1499795951 |
+-------------+-------+------------+
```

I tried getting the values using get_json_object

```
select get_json_object(json_col,'$.metrics.cpu.cpu_user[1]') from json_table
```

,this gives me

```
[0.3,1499795951]
```

How do I use the explode function from here to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  'cpu_user'      as metric_type 
       ,val_ts[0]       as val
       ,val_ts[1]       as ts

from   (select  split(m.col,',') as val_ts

        from    json_table j
                lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(json_col,'$.metrics.cpu.cpu_user[*]'),'^\\[\\[|\\]\\]$',''),'\\],\\[')) m
        ) m
;
```

---

```
+-------------+-----+------------+
| metric_type | val |     ts     |
+-------------+-----+------------+
| cpu_user    | 0.7 | 1499795941 |
| cpu_user    | 0.3 | 1499795951 |
+-------------+-----+------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also implement SerDe and InputFormat interface based on JSON data, instead of using UDF.

here are some referance:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/
https://github.com/xjtuzxh/inceptor-inputformat

Comment: So are you saying Hive UDF's or the internal functions can't parse a JSON?

Comment: I just give you alternative method, I didn't say UDF  cannot  parse a JSON